# compare varchar with number in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

table

```
user(varchar40)      credit(varchar40)
u1                   400
u2                   500
u3                   600
u4                   650
```

and query

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT `user` FROM `tbl` WHERE `credit` < '8'");
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($sql);$i++)

{
echo mysql_result($sql,$i,0);
}
```

and result
u1
u2
u3
u4

because credit is varchar only first number compare and return all user

how i do correct compare without change table ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, why are storing numbers as string? anyway, you can cast the value into number using `CAST()`

```
SELECT `user` FROM `tbl` WHERE CAST(`credit` AS SIGNED) < 8
```

if I were you, you should fix it to correct data type to avoid casting the column always just for comparison. To do this, alter the table and add extra column, an `INTEGER` column. `UPDATE` the table by casting the column `credit` into the new added column and drop column `credit`.

Comment: im not developer im only update this stupid script . thanks its work.